# Rails - Scope and fin_by_sql question

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, scope

Given my three models here:

```
class Classroom < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :students
  has_many :slideshows
  has_many :grades

class Slideshow < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :classroom
  has_many :grades

class Grade < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :slideshow
  belongs_to :classroom
```

I have created a `scope` to make the query I need in the `classroom model` :

```
scope :result, lambda { 
  joins(:slideshows, :grades).
  where("classrooms.id = slideshows.classroom_id AND slideshows.id = grades.slideshows_id ").
  select("classroom.name, SUM (grades.english), SUM(grades.biology) ").
  group("classroom.name ").
  order("SUM(grades.english+grades.biology) DESC ")

  }
```

The question is that in my controller I can't manage to get this working. I have tried 2 things:

```
@variable = Classroom.result

@variable = Classroom.find_by_sql(:result)
```

First option seems like the query works but I can't retrieve the results. Second option shut downs my server. Any ideia on how can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass block inside the your second options. for that you have to write SQL query.

```
@variable = Classroom.find_by_sql("Your query goes here..!!")
```

Comment: Hello. Thanks for the answer. There is no way I can take this query out of the controller and put it in the model? Can't use scop or anything like that somehow?